# A Version of Weiestrass Function : Which is easy to prove Satisfying Holder Condition and Not Of BV

Tags: bounded-variation

I am looking for the function that satisfies two characteristics - first, satisfying the holder condition and the second, not of BV. One recommended me a Weiestrass functiuon, however, most generalized version of Weiestrass is too complex to prove the characteristic of not of Bounded Variation.

Any more specified version of Weiestrass function that could be recommended?

Comment: what is BV..???

Comment: @Masacroso bounded variation. Edited the OP